# Universal store app getting data from server

Tags: sql, win-universal-app

I want to build an app that gets data from a server and it displays it in xaml. I'm new to universal programs and in windows store apps in general. I haven't found anything useful yet as ms sql solutions require libraries that is not allowed for universal store apps :(  
P.S.: The answer in [how to connect sql server 2008 R2 with windows store application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989594/how-to-connect-sql-server-2008-r2-with-windows-store-application) did not answer my question, but Jeffery's answer did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to connect sql server 2008 R2 with windows store application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989594/how-to-connect-sql-server-2008-r2-with-windows-store-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t connect to a MS SQL Server directly from the Windows App. The common way is host a data service and the app query the data through the REST API.

**App -> data service (e.g. OData service) -> database (e.g. MS SQL Server)**

In this case, you can deploy the SQL Server Data Service on IIS.

How to: [Deploying OData Services using IIS & SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg192995.aspx)

Then you use the [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298639) to retrieve the data from service.

Similar Question:
[Windows phone 8.1 app connect with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872666/windows-phone-8-1-app-connect-with-a-database)

Comment: Thank you I will look into that later

Comment: Okay, so I looked over and I got confused because I'm not sure what this Adventure works thing is and I used my server connection instead, since I already have an SQL server up in AWS. Which steps should I follow or which steps should I skip?

Comment: The essential idea is using the full .NET to connect to the SQL Database and expose the data service through HTTP or HTTPS, then you can consume the data service in you App. I updated a similar question for your reference

Comment: Thank you. I'll let you know how it went

Comment: Okay, so now I understand the algorithm you are talking about. I'm quite familiar with mySQL and php so I think I will build it in php and retrieve it using the [Httpclient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298639) you mentioned. Would this work?