# SQL access from a Windows 10 Universal Application

Tags: sql-server, win-universal-app, uwp

I'm trying to make an application for my company which will run on Windows 10 tablets connected to a main server over the internet via a VPN. I have the VPN and devices established and am trying a sort of "Hello World" with a tablet.

Here is my problem: My app will require access to the SQL Server running on main server hosting the VPN.

The SQL Server is already configured to allow access over the network and has been tested. If I write a simple WPF application, I can run it from the tablet and the SQL connection works perfectly.

So why is it a problem?

Because for the life of me I can't figure out how to connect to an SQL database from a Windows Universal Application. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and the "Blank App (Universal Windows)" solution template. The System.Data.SqlClient namespace is not available by default, no framework assemblies are listed when I try to add a reference, and when I browse to the System.Data.dll to add it manually, I get other errors.

The above makes me feel like I'm going about this wrong; database access is a basic need for an application and shouldn't be this hard to implement. Can anyone tell me how to go about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to connect sql server 2008 R2 with windows store application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989594/how-to-connect-sql-server-2008-r2-with-windows-store-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't directly connect to a full blown SQL DB from a WUA. Only to an SQLite one.

Similar question with more detailed answers-

[Universal store app getting data from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063814/c-sharp-universal-store-app-getting-data-from-server)

Answer (score -2):

There is a class called SqlConnection which you can use to connect to a database that does the same thing.

Here is an example I found in msdn.

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security =SSPI;");
```

Or you can create your own api on your server and connect to it using ajax methods like XMLHttpRequest().open('GET','stuff.aspx',true)

Comment: The `SqlConnection` class is in `System.Data.SqlClient` which is not currently available for UWPapps.